# retrieve value from database and assign it in to string variable C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows-mobile-6

I want to retrieve value from table. Please guys help me.
The thing is I want to get that value and check it with a string value.

this code is not working:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT username FROM tmpusername WHERE _id=1", connection);

SqlCeDataReader usernameRdr = null;

usernameRdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while (usernameRdr.Read()){
    string username11 = usernameRdr["username11"].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about *"not working"*?

Comment: What is not working? What do you expect to happen that does not?

Comment: i want to do get some value from the table and i want to check it with the string value

Answer (score 2):

use `username` for accessing column.

```
string username11 = usernameRdr["username"].ToString();
```

Your select command is specifying `Select username` and later you are accessing it using `username11`. That is why you are not getting the value, instead you should be getting an exception.

Comment: i want to do get some value from the table and i want to check it with the string value ...

Answer (score 1):

Change it to be :

```
string username11 = usernameRdr["username"].ToString();
```

The data reader indexer takes the name of the column in the SQL result set which is "SELECT **username**..." in your SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see if **dataReader** returns any rows first, to prevent null value returns from the database which may cause [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so use the following;

> > string username11=string.empty;
>
> ```
> if (usernameRdr.hasRows)
> {
> while (reader.Read())
> {
> username11=usernameRdr["username"].ToString();
> }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

for handling null values change to,

```
string username11 = Convert.ToString(usernameRdr["username"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string username11 = (string)usernameRdr["username"];
```

You have entered wrong column name `username11` instead of `username`.